# What's a good way to show previous versions of records?

Tags: forms, versioning

I'm designing a typical database application. Now I wounder how I should present previous versions of records.

I have two views for records now:

**Create/Update view**

[image]

**Read view**

[image]

But how should I show previous versions of the records?

I have two ideas, either as a table, with a version per row, **or** I could do a view similar to the "Read view" but have two side by side and present current version with the previous and also let the user browser older "pages".

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: whats likely to be the difference between the records between dates?

Comment: @colmcq Any field. E.g. another "itemgroup" or a new "name" and "item no".

Answer (score 3):

I would also highlight the differences between previous records and current records, as that is likely to be the focus for anyone viewing previous records.

Answer (score 0):

in light of the comment: tabulate records and add extra attribute for date. Allow column sort via date or indeed and other attribute. On click record go to your edit view.

In other words all you're doing is changing the read only view.

eg something like this: click row to reach edit mode. there are also add record and delete record buttons but they seem to have got chopped off, and ignore the numbers at the bottom.

[image]